# Calling VBA subroutine does not work when it is called from inside of another subroutine

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to try and call a series of sub routines from the main sub routine. When I combine all of the subroutines with code similar to the following, I get #N/A for the cells that the formula is suppose to be ignoring.

```
Sub Main()

'Turn off autocalculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
'*********************************************************
'A bunch of other code
'*********************************************************

Call Sub_Routine1
Call Sub_Routine2
Call Sub_Routine3
Call Sub_Routine4
Call Sub_Routine5
Call Sub_Routine6
Call Sub_Routine7

'This is the sub routine that is not working correctly
Call Material_Formulas

'Turn back on the autocalculation function
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

'*********************************************************
'A bunch of other code
'*********************************************************  
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image: Combined_Call]

When I remove the Material_Formulas subroutine from the Main sub routine and run it separately using the following script, it executes as it is suppose to and looks like the image bellow.

```
Private Sub Material_Formulas()

'Turn on manual calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim tiesMaterial As String
Dim result As String
lRow = Sheets("Material").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
lCol = Sheets("Material").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column

'Starts the count at column CU
endCount = lCol - 1    
    For c = 99 To endCount
        For r = 3 To lRow        
        tiesMaterial = Cells(r, 87).Value

        'Looks to see if the cells starting at CU2 contains a number and then iterates through each cell in row 3 to add a formula
        If tiesMaterial = "TIES MATERIAL" Then

            'Defines the unique ID and calendar year cells for the index-match-match function
            materialID = Sheets("Material").Cells(r, "CQ").Address(False, False)
            materialYear = Sheets("Material").Cells(2, c).Address(False, False)

            'Starting in cell CU3 it adds the formula =INDEX(BOM_Summary_Array,MATCH(CQ3,BOM_Summary_ID,0),MATCH(CU2,BOM_Summary_Head,0))
            Sheets("Material").Cells(r, c).Formula = "=INDEX(BOM_Summary_Array,MATCH(Material!" & materialID & ",BOM_Summary_ID,0),MATCH(Material!" & materialYear & ",BOM_Summary_Head,0))"                 
        End If

        Next r
    Next c     
'Turn on the auto calculation function
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

[image: Separate_Call]

What am I doing wrong? How does it run fine when I manually and independently select it but it fails when I combine it with the other sub routines?

Comment: When you say *"fails"* do you mean it does nothing or it throws an error **??**

Comment: What is the formula in the cell, is it correct? if not what should the correct formula be?

Comment: Are the years across row 2 actual dates formatted as `yyyy` or integers from 2012 to 2021?

Comment: The cells that have #N/A should not be ignored. In those cells the parameter that is suppose to initiate the formula (TIES MATERIAL ) is missing so those rows should be skipped or ignored. They would then have the original value. The second image from above is what it should look like. In both cases they are numbers and not formatted as dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything else you need to improve your code. I can pretty much guarantee that this is likely happening because of poorly written code. For example:

```
materialID = Sheets("Material").Cells(r, "CQ").Address(False, False)
materialYear = Sheets("Material").Cells(2, c).Address(False, False)
```

Note that `materialID` and `materialYear` are never declared. This means they are of the type Variant (you need to add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code modules for this exact reason). The funny thing about Variants is they, you guessed it, vary. `MaterialID` could be a `string`, an `int`, a `long`, a `decimal`, a `date`, an `array`, a `range`, etc. We can assume that the address of the range is going into `materialID`, but we can't be certain.

Additionally, notice the pesky `Sheets("Material")`. What this actually is saying is ActiveWorkboook.Sheets("Material")`. Qualify your references otherwise you have pretty much no clue what is *actually* happening.

What can easily be happening in the case of your code is that the address is correctly going into `materialID` as a `string`, but it is the address from another workbook with a sheet named "Material". Unlikely, but possible.

What we do know is quite likely is that the `ActiveWorkbook` is changing in some capacity, likely in `Sub_Routine7` (sidenote here, you must descriptively name subroutines otherwise your code is nowhere near maintainability).

Good luck with this, but I highly suggest not bothering to try to debug the situation until you have qualified your ranges, declared all your variables, and added `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon! Sorry for the misunderstanding the numbered subroutines were not their actual names they were for pseudo code illustration purposes. I eventually got it to work by adding a reference to the active workbook page that the material formulas are referencing.